# How to create a case in a Salesforce using python

Tags: python, api, salesforce, chatbot

please help, I am trying to create a case in Salesforce account using external live agent chat.
Like email to case or whats app to case  works how external the chat-bot works in Salesforce?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the standard REST API Endpoint URI

> First done authentication

```html
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
sf = Salesforce(
username='user name of salesforce account', 
password='password', 
security_token='token')
```

> URI : /services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Case

> Operation : POST
> Body : JSON

> Sample  post parameter list

```html
data ={
    "Subject" : "Radio is repaired",
    "Priority" : "high",
    "Description":"Radio has damaged because of handling."
}

x = sf.Case.create(data)
```

> It create a case in Salesforce case object using REST API